# Bash script process substitution Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process-substitution

I want to run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo <(true)
```

I run it as:

```
sh file.sh
```

And I get "`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`" . I found some similar situations but still can't solve this.
I'm a beginner at shell scripting , but as I understand:

1. the shebang I use is correct and chooses the bash shell , so the process substitution syntax should work
2. I try the same from the command line and it works. I checked with `echo $0` and it gives me "`bash`" , so what's the difference from running the command in the command line and from a script that invokes the same shell?

Maybe it's something simple, but I couldn't find an explanation or solution.

Comment: How do you run this script? I can reproduce this with `sh ./script.sh`.

Comment: @Cyrus and I can't with `./file.sh`:) I.e. it works for me as it should.

Comment: if not solved yet, does the

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should run your script with `bash`, i.e. either `bash ./script.sh` or making use of the shebang by `./script.sh` after setting it to executable. Only running it with `sh ./script.sh` do I get your error, as commented by Cyrus.

See also: [role of shebang at unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600)

Comment: I used sh file.sh... I assumed that it always lookes at the shebang declaration. Thanks for the link , it helped me a lot - when I specify the interpeter at command line the shebang is ignored. So I should use "bash file.sh - determines interpreter from command line or ./file.sh - determines from the shebang declaration"

Comment: @KatrinnaL `./file.sh` is preferred; the file's shebang line should "know" which shell to use, and you might not. The only real reason to use `bash file.sh` is if the shebang is wrong (or missing) or the file isn't executable -- but in those cases, it's better to fix the problem and then use `./file.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

**sh file.sh**

errorsh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

solution:

**bash file.sh**

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32039027/2227743).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31250558)