# syntax error when compare two files using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to save the result of the comparison of two files into a varible, I use the code:

```
LOCAL=test1
REMOTE=test2
msg=$(comm -3 <(sort ${LOCAL}) <(sort ${REMOTE}))
echo $msg
```

I could run each line in the Shell but if I save it as script, it show errors:

```
test.sh: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: command substitution: line 3: `comm -3 <(sort ${LOCAL}) <(sort ${REMOTE})'
```

---

Solved it:
Run the code using

```
bash ./test.sh
```

as the answer in [Bash script process substitution Syntax error: "(" unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038974/bash-script-process-substitution-syntax-error-unexpected)

Comment: This is presumably not `bash`

Comment: If you're running your script with `sh yourscript`, or starting it with `#!/bin/sh`, then its interpreter is only guaranteed to be POSIX-baseline, without extensions such as process substitutions.

Comment: BTW, a few notes -- all-caps variable names are used by POSIX-specified convention for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph. And you're missing quotes -- consider using http://shellcheck.net; right now, your code doesn't preserve newlines in the output from `comm`, for example, because it's running `echo $msg` instead of `echo "$msg"`; this is also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).