# Linux command runs fine on shell but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have `2` files in `Linux` like below

`file1`

```
test_1
test_3
test_5
test_6
```

`file2`

```
test_1,smoke_test
test_2,rain_test
test_3,sun_test
test_4,wind_test
```

I want to compare these two files and delete the tables in `file1` that are present in `file2` that is the first part before `comma(,)`

Output required:

`file3`

```
test_5
test_6
```

I have tried like below

```
grep -v -Ff <(cut -d',' -f1 file2) file1 >file3
```

I got what I want.

Now when I write a script It throws an error

```
new.sh: line 67: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

`Script`

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -v -Ff <(cut -d',' -f1 file2) file1 >file3
```

I'm running it with:

```
sh -x script.sh
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Process substitution `<(...)`  is not supported in `sh`, use `bash` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the script using `sh` rather than `bash`, so you're not getting the `bash` extensions like `<(...)` process substitution. Run it with:

```
bash -x script.sh
```

or just:

```
./script.sh
```

The latter will use the interpreter named in the `#!` line.

Comment: I have a question if I run this script as a cronjob will it take `./script.sh` or `sh -x script.sh`. I am new to Linux

Comment: @Barmar, you know this is a duplicate as well as anyone here. *tsk*

Comment: Don't use `sh`!!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, but I wasn't sure how to find the dupes. I'll save them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The dupes seem about incorrect `#!` lines, not about using `sh` explicitly from the shell. There's probably better dupes.

Comment: @Barmar, a fair point; added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038974/bash-script-process-substitution-syntax-error-unexpected to the top of the list.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I edited that question to be clearer, and added it to my portential dupe list.